# Generate a beta distribution and plot it on the same beta density

Tags: matlab, random

Generate a sample $X_1, ..., X_n$, of size $n = 1000$ from the beta law and, draw their histogram.

Draw on the same graph the probability density. using Matlab

I can't plot them on the same graph

here is my code

```
function [ X] = Beta( a,b, n )
X=zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
u1 = rand(a,1);
Y1=-(1/b)*log(prod(u1));

u2 = rand(a,1);
Y2=-(1/b)*log(prod(u2));

X(i,1)=Y1/(Y1+Y2);
end
x = 0:0.01:1;
y1 = betapdf(x,2,2);

hist(X)
hold on
plot(x,y1)
hold off
```

Comment: Hard to see what you try to do. You create a function Beta() that you don't use afterwards. If you want to fit a Beta density to your $X$, checkout the histfit function

Comment: Looks like this may be due to the histogram and PDF plot not have ing same y-axis scale. A few things are possible: 1) normalize your histogram elements by the total number of counts; 2) use [`plotyy`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) or the newer [`yyaxis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html) to plot with two different y-axes.

Comment: Also, in current versions of Matlab, the `hist` command is deprecated. You should look at [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) instead, which even has options to normalize the bin counts.